# Put retrieved data from MySQL query into DataFrame pandas by a for loop

Tags: python, mysql

I have one database with two tables, both have a column called barcode, the aim is to retrieve barcode from one table and search for the entries in the other where extra information of that certain barcode is stored. I would like to have bothe retrieved data to be saved in a DataFrame. The problem is when I want to insert the retrieved data into DataFrame from the second query, it stores only the last entry:

```
 import mysql.connector
 import pandas as pd
 cnx = mysql.connector(user,password,host,database)
 query_barcode = ("SELECT barcode FROM barcode_store")
 cursor = cnx.cursor()
 cursor.execute(query_barcode)
 data_barcode = cursor.fetchall()
```

Up to this point everything works smoothly, and here is the part with problem:

```
 query_info = ("SELECT product_code FROM product_info WHERE barcode=%s")
 for each_barcode in data_barcode:
      cursor.execute(query_info % each_barcode)
      pro_info = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

pro_info contains only the last matching barcode information! While I want to retrieve all the information for each data_barcode match.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are consistently overriding existing `pro_info` with new data in each loop iteration. You should rather do something like:

```
query_info = ("SELECT product_code FROM product_info")
cursor.execute(query_info)
pro_info = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

Making so many `SELECT`s is redundant since you can get all records in one `SELECT` and instantly insert them to your `DataFrame`.

@edit: However if you need to use the `WHERE` statement to fetch only specific products, you need to store records in a `list` until you insert them to `DataFrame`. So your code will eventually look like:

```
pro_list = []
query_info = ("SELECT product_code FROM product_info WHERE barcode=%s")
for each_barcode in data_barcode:
     cursor.execute(query_info % each_barcode)
     pro_list.append(cursor.fetchone())
pro_info = pd.DataFrame(pro_list)
```

Cheers!

Comment: I understand your point, but then the WHERE condition is gone, in this way I will receive all the product info and not only the ones which the barcodes match from the other table. Is my explanation clear?

Comment: Nhor thank you for the advice, at first it did not work, it was still writing only the last entry, then I thought I should change it to the following and now it works very well:  pro_list.append(cursor.fetchone())

Comment: ah yeah sorry, i didn't notice this one. ofc you did right thing to correct it and i'll correct my answer as well